# onHover being triggered by invisible part of menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

[On my website](http://rossiterandco-2.hs-sites.com/) if you hover anywhere below the 3 colourful header buttons i.e "Marketing" "Training" and "Specialists area", you notice the hidden menu for **"Specialists area"** is triggered.

Can someone please help me understand why this behaviour is happening as i would like to have menu triggered ONLY when you hover on the **"Specialists area"** button itself.

NOTE: "Marketing" & "Training" buttons are working as intended. i.e triggering their menus ONLY when the hover is inside the respective button.

Comment: Try inspecting the element giving you the problem, or provide us some code to look at.

Comment: Probably because your menu isn't actually hidden but only transparent and gets opaque when you hover on it.

Comment: @somethinghere yes it is transparent....but so are the other two menus for "Marketing" & "Training" buttons.....but these do not behave like this....you can hover just below the "marketing button", without triggering its transparent menu.

Comment: @LukeAlvinMadzedze in all likelihood thats because this on is the top layer and the biggest one. Which means you cant hover on the other ones without hovering on this one, meaning you always see this one.

Comment: @LukeAlvinMadzedze I'd love to help actually, but your code is so convoluted, filled with classes, `div`s, `ul`s, `li`s, `a`s ... Its an impenetrable wall. I testing using max-height and overflow-hidden which get invalidated on hover, but that doesn't work because of... Other classes somewhere. Sorry pal, provide better code if you want anyone to look at it but this is too... Convoluted.

Comment: @LukeAlvinMadzedze guessing you've fixed this as it doens't behave as you describe for me ? (I'm using Firefox in case thats relevant).. could you put the fix in as an answer ?

Comment: @somethinghere sorry pal about the classes everywhere, thats hubspot for you. iam actually trying to hack their bult-in menu...which i can only modify via css overriding. 90% of the css is all hubspot....i just changed the way the items are laid out with css.